# wp7 delete picture from saved pictures album

Tags: windows-phone-7, picturegallery

In my wp7 app, I am able to save pictures taken from a camera in the saved pictures album and able to read them later. If a particular record is deleted in the app, I want to delete the associated picture with that entity from the saved pictures album.

Has anyone tried this? I don't seem to find any methods on the media library to perform this?

Pratik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no API for removing the user's pictures from their device.

The phone's owner is in exclusive control of this function.

An alternative approach may work for you to keep pictures in isolated storage and offer the user the ability to optionally put them in their media library, passing control of that capability to the phone's owner as well.

Comment: Mick, from all the things I read, I was thinking it is probably not allowed. Thanks for confirming it for me.  I have modified the code now where the photo is now written to IS and the user can Send to the Photo Hub if they wish to.